# Someone in the office drinks water as a defence mechanism

Tags: psychology, discipline

Someone appears to drink water as a defence mechanism when in trouble in the office.
As a point is being raised or feedback given, the person always brings their glass to their mouth and will drink (or at least seem to drink) from it constantly until the conversation is over.

Is this a normal thing?
Could it mean anything?

**EDIT:** Seeing as this question is being misunderstood and misinterpreted I will clarify the following:

I have noticed when delivering constructive feedback/criticism of a member of staffs work, as is done with other members of staff, they seem to defend their self by holding a glass to their mouth and drinking/pretending to drink

I am trying to establish if anyone else has experienced something similar in this position, and if I should be concerned the person only every performs this action when being presented with something one could deem as negative

If this person is struggling and panicking when issues/feedback is raised this needs to be handled separately to allow the person to feel more comfortable and understand I can help improve their knowledge/skill set or what ever may improve their confidence and I am trying to establish if others think this may be an approproiate course of action

Comment: Well, you've identified it as a defence mechanism... what more do you want? Trying to diagnose it as unusual or as any particular condition is inappropriate. What about picking up on it, and maybe approaching the person from a less confrontational angle to avoid making them defensive?

Comment: So how would this matter to you in any event? Are you somehow harmed by a nervous gesture someone else makes?

Comment: It is more to assess if said person may need a 1-2-1 chat, a little more informal, see if they are uncomfortable in some way, or feel they are struggling within their role

Comment: The better way to find that out may be to just ask, rather than trying to interpret nervous gestures?

Comment: I'm not sure this question should be answered as asked. "Could it mean anything" is a question for a psychology (hence the tag). If it were worded as "how should I respond when I'm trying to give this person feedback and they cut me off by drinking", that would fit better for this site.

Comment: When I feel anxious I sometimes give visual queues with my mouth which if noticed makes me more anxious. Drinking water or chewing gum helps with this.
I don't think it is fair to use it as a negative.

Comment: Could you clarify the behaviour in your question? Is it just a nervous tic where the individual keeps sipping (or pretending to) while talking? Or is he doing so to avoid participating in the conversation in a "I can't talk I'm drinking" kind of way? The first is a quirk, the second can be a legitimate performance issue; though neither is really any of your business if you're not managing this person.

Comment: Is the way someone reacts to stress any of your business? As long as no one gets hurt, they choose however they react so far as I am concerned.

Comment: Does this individual "come up for air" at all, or is the cup stuck to their mouth for the duration of the conversation without a break? If they're just sipping, and otherwise still listening, and there is evidence afterward that the feedback has been heard, just ignore it. But if their cup-to-face behavior is analogous to putting their fingers in their ears and singing "la-la-la-I-can't-hear-you", then there is a performance problem that needs to be addressed. If you are the person's manager, you are the one to address it frankly and head on. "Leave your drink at your desk and come visit."

Comment: I am not concerned that someone might be drinking water to avoid talking to me or anyone else, because that won't work. We pop the question and we wait until he finishes sipping the water, at which point he'll have to answer the question. If we are out to get him to talk, we'll make him talk.

Comment: Are we talking a bunch of little sips?  A ten second sip?  A single two minute sip?  If it's the third and done in front of clients, I would bring it up.

Comment: As mentioned below in a comment on the chosen answer, the drinking is only observed when I am passing on feedback of a negative nature and similar situations and I am going to deem it as a nervous tick.

To those asking, the "drinking" is constant, as in what ever is being said can last a good minute or 2 and the employee holds the glass to their mouth through out the entire thing which is why the question was being raised as a "do i need to look deeper into this".

Comment: There is nothing here for you to "look into". Just ignore it, the way you'd ignore other kinds of fidgeting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are reading way too much into this.

I do this sometimes when I am thinking. I sometimes have to fidget or otherwise "use my hands" when I am thinking, I don't like blindly staring. I have a "thinking face" that happens.

If I have a glass of water I will often take a drink to avoid the, "enderland is just staring and not responding" problem.

Also, some people have things they do when they are uncomfortable/nervous that are similarly unconscious.

Comment: I think this is similar to, but not the same as, the "going to the bathroom until unpleasant discussion is over" tactic... ;)

Comment: Right. And other people look away, and others bite their nails, and others start drummng with their fingers on their desk, and others start moving in their chairs, or fidgeting with their pen or papers, and still others . .. ...

Comment: It was only noticed as it only happens when the tone of the conversation is slightly negative.
During normal day to day work conversations, or when passing on details of a task etc the drinking doesn't occur

It is probably just a "nervous tick" when the tone of the conversation is negative and the person is feeling "told off" by what is being said to them

Comment: When I'm nervous, or stressed, or sometimes listening intently -- or even just bored -- I may fidget with an object or doodle on the corner of a piece of paper. We all have habits of that sort. If this person's keep-the-hands-busy object is a cup of water, why does that matter to you?

Comment: I think you are missing the point @keshlam .... The reason the point is being raised is that I am trying to determine if the person could be struggling with the workload, or struggling with constructive feedback/criticism then I would need to discuss with them if there is anything further I can do to assist them instead of ignoring the issue and the person feel like they are drowning! (no pun intended)

Comment: Don't try to psychoanalyze them. Just talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a normal thing? Could it mean anything?

There is no real definition of normal seeing as everyone is different. Normal is relative. Your colleague's compulsive water consumption is likely nothing more than a vice/coping mechanism like nail biting and other similar stress responses. Granted your colleague could be setting themselves up for major medical problems from compulsive water drinking as a stress response if the volume of water and frequency are high enough. If you're concerned, look at what may be causing this response in them. Ask if you can be of assistance and see if your willingness to help them with work aides in reducing the response (if you're available to assist them).

You can just make a comment to them in passing such as "I notice you drink a lot of water. Do you get dehydrated easily?" Such a question is non threatening, non prying and you may even be helping them realize they are doing something they're not consciously aware of. Many people have stress responses they aren't aware of until after the fact when the stressful event has passed.

Comment: I would avoid even making a comment about dehydration since it would likely have little positive effect and *does* risk making the other person uncomfortable. Excessive thirst can be benign, have a medical origin (it's common in diabetics) or be due to medication and you don't want to risk invading on someone's privacy as a coworker. Concerned colleagues should probably ask HR or a manager to bring it up with the individual privately. Sustained fluid consumption of 0.8-1 liter per hour is problematic.

Comment: @Lilienthal Indeed. If you wanted to make a helpful comment you could talk about how they felt about the situation. From that, depending on the relationship you have, you could even bring up the water. But as I said, very much depends on the relationship you already have - you cannot 'coach' people without their consent.